# Getting large estimates of error while using EIGEN sparse library

Tags: eigen

I am using the EIGEN sparse library to solve a system. I tried to test on a smaller matrix and got the estimated error close to zero. I attach the snippet of the code below.

```
MatrixXd Dense(4,4);
Dense<<2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
       0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,
       0.0,0.0,5.0,0.0,
       0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0;
Vector4d b(4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 1.0),xsol;

cout << "The least-squares solution is:\n"
     << Dense.jacobiSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).solve(b) << endl;

SpMat SparseA;
SparseA = Dense.sparseView();

cout<<SparseA<<endl;

BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double> > bicg;

bicg.compute(SparseA);
xsol = bicg.solve(b);

std::cout << "#iterations:     " << bicg.iterations() << std::endl;
std::cout << "estimated error: " << bicg.error()      << std::endl;

// update  and solve again
xsol = bicg.solve(b);

cout << "Sparse Matrix Solution is:\n" << xsol << endl;**
```

This is what I get when I run the code:

> iterations:     1
>
> estimated error: 0
>
> Sparse Matrix Solution is:
>
> 2
>     4
>   1.6
>     1

Now comes the problem I scale up the system and try to solve I get huge estimated errors.  How do I resolve this.  By the way I follow the same procedure of defining a dense matrix and converting them into a sparse one before solving the system. The code snippet is as follows

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;
SpMat SparseKGl;
VectorXd wsol;
SparseKGl = KGl.sparseView();

BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double> > bicg; 
wsol=bicg.compute(SparseKGl).solve(ForceGl);

std::cout << "iterations:     " << bicg.iterations() << std::endl;
std::cout << "estimated error: " << bicg.error()      << std::endl;

// update  and solve again
wsol = bicg.solve(ForceGl);
```

The output I get is

> iterations:     22
>
> estimated error: 70549

Can anyone please provide some insights into the same?

Regards

Comment: `BiCGSTAB` is an iterative solver and the convergence speed strongly depends on the condition of the matrix. It is therefore not really possible to directly answer your question ...

Comment: Also, what's the output of `bicg.info()`? Is it equal to `Eigen::Success`? Using a ILUT preconditioner often helps a lot: `BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double>,IncompleteLUT<double> >`.

Comment: This is amazing ILUT preconditioner really works well and I get a error of less than e-18.  Thanks a lot for the suggestion